# Add List instead of Replace List for TableView DataSource

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am currently trying to add pagination to my Instagram App and have managed to replace the List that provides the Data Source with the new data, but I want to add it to the existing List so that when I scroll back up it would show the most recent picture. Here is my approach right now:

```
            var request = new RestRequest { RootElement = "data", Resource = "/users/self/feed" };
            request.AddParameter ("access_token", instagramAccessToken);

            var client = new RestClient ("https://api.instagram.com/v1");
            client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (response.Content);

                string nextURL = rootObject.pagination.next_url;
                //// Create Next Client
                var requestBack = new RestRequest ();
                var clientBack = new RestClient (nextURL);

                // GET Next Response
                clientBack.ExecuteAsync(requestBack, responseBack => {
                    var rootObjectBack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (responseBack.Content);
                    table.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                        // Create list that contains newly attained JSON
                        List<Datum> instagramData = rootObjectBack.data;
                        // Create dummy list for other values
                        List<Datum> sloppy = null;
                        // Send list that contains data, and the sloppy which doesnt contain anything to the Facebook and Twitter Values.
                        table.Source = new TableSource<Datum>(instagramData, sloppy, sloppy);
                        table.ReloadData ();
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Jason How would i Make it so that the new data is added to the Old List so it displays all of it on the same TableView

Comment: @Jason Like in the Twitter app and you scroll down and loads more but when you scroll back up the new info is there too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<x> A = initial data
List<x> B = new data
A.AddRange(B);
```

A now has B appended to the end

to access the public List (assuming it's called "Data") inside of your existing source

```
((TableSource<Datum>)table.Source).Data
```

Comment: Yes but my list is in my `TableSource<T>` Class. Its a public variable how would I reference it from here?

Comment: I fixed the problem but i seemed to run into another issue... When I scroll to the bottom of the screen it puts the next set of images but it displays that same set when I pull down again instead of bringing the next set.